# Solve the recurrence relation $T(n)=2T(n/2)+\log(n)$ given that $T(1) = 1$

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

Question:

> Assume that a recurrence relation is given as below:
>
> $T(n)=2T(n/2)+\log(n)$
>
> and we know that $T(1) = 1$
>
> We want to solve the relation (find an explicit definition of $T(n)$
> which does not rely on itself).

My solving:

> I wanted to solve it using substitution method but when i tried I get the series
> $$\log(n)+2\log(n/2)+4\log(n/4)+8\log(n/8) ... 2^k\log(n/2^k)$$
> which I am not able to solve.

Comment: Is there any easy way for adding nicely formatted mathematical expressions on stack overflow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\log(n) = \log_2 n$ we have

$$
T\left(2^{\log_2 n}\right) = 2T\left(2^{\log_2 \frac n2}\right)+\log_2 n
$$

now calling $\mathcal{T}(\cdot) = T\left(2^{(\cdot)}\right)$ and $z = \log_2 n$ we follow with the linear recurrence

$$
\mathcal{T}(n) = 2\mathcal{T}(z-1) + z
$$

with solution

$$
\mathcal{T}(n) =2^{z-1}c_0 + 2^{z+1}-(z+2)
$$

and now going backwards with $z = \log_2 n$ we arrive at

$$
T(n) = \frac n2 c_0 +2(n-1)-\log_2 n
$$

Finally with $T(1) = 1$ follows $c_0 = 2$

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I didn't downvote it

Comment: Is there any easy way for adding nicely formatted mathematical expressions on stack overflow ?

Comment: Some software applications have nice TeX output  as for instance MATHEMATICA.

Comment: can you name few.. I am too noob in this

Comment: Regarding the formula edition format there are some good LaTeX editors totally free like those shown here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence relation is not well defined. You can't calculate, for example, $T(3)$.

Comment: This is a recurrence over the numbers $2^k$ with $k\in\mathbb{N}$.